# References doesn' t getUpdated After passed to a class?

Tags: java, oop

```
class Main
{

    public static void main()
    {
        Student one=new Student();
        one.setName("firstname");

        AllStudent all=new AllStudent();
        all.add(one);

        // Now changing name of student

        one.setName("secondname");

        // Here I getAll Students

        Collection<Student> cs=all.getAll();


            java.util.Iterator<Student> itr=cs.iterator();


            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Student rgc=itr.next();
                System.out.println(rgc.getName());
            }
    }

    clas public Student
    {

        String name;

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name=name;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    clas public AllStudent
    {

        Collection<Student> stds;

        public void addAll(Collection<Student> stds)
        {
            this.stds=stds;
        }

        public void add(Student std)
        {
            stds.add(std);
        }

        public Collection<Student> getAll()
        {
            return stds;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this will give me "firstname".

But I want to get "secondname". So what I have to do? If any change in API or to create new class?

Comment: Show the constructor for Student and AllStudent classes. Something tells me the problem is in your constructor ... unless of course, the problems lies elsewhere in unmentioned code.

Comment: This shouldn't work at all. You never initialize the collection `stds`.

Comment: What do you mean by get `secondname`. You have only name in your `class student`. If you want more info about the student to be stored, then add them to this class, think that should be enough

Comment: @trutheality That is why I wanted to see if he left out his constructors bc that was the first thought I had ... he could just be omitting the constructors however.

Comment: @Matthew: Yep. My comment was towards the OP before I noticed that it isn't even runnable code (`clas` keywords). The problem in the complete code is definitely omitted, and the constructors are the most likely place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it's your code i just implement something in that

```
package pkg;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Student one=new Student();
        one.setName("firstname");

        AllStudent all=new AllStudent();
        all.add(one);

        // Now changing name of student

        one.setName("secondname");

        // Here I getAll Students

        Collection<Student> cs=all.getAll();

        java.util.Iterator<Student> itr=cs.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Student rgc=itr.next();
            System.out.println(rgc.getName());
        }

    }
    static class Student{
        private String name;
        void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    }    
    static class AllStudent{
        Collection<Student> stds = new HashSet<Main.Student>();

        void addAll(Collection<Student> stds){
            this.stds = stds;
        }

        void add(Student std){
            this.stds.add(std);
        }
        public Collection<Student> getAll(){
            return stds;
        }

    }
}
```

I have run and got the secondname

Comment: Can you Explain me where AllStudent and Student objects are stored on Heap and Stack as they are static....? and how I got second name.

Comment: @Nitul it will not add the object as value but it will add the object as reference. here is the more explanation about this http://www.chetanasforum.com/index.php?showtopic=1474

Comment: Now assume that my Student , AllStudent and Main classes are in individual package tehn   ?

Comment: so what it doesn't effect in background process try it with create individual class. static i use because when we use Inner class object into any static method that inner class should declare as static. If you create individual class then no need to define static

Comment: What if I move all code to any non static method? 
Example : I copy code from main() method to void go() method. then calling go() from main().

Comment: then the inner class which was define as static are run and also if you remove the static then also run correctly. I think you confuse with the static keyword

Comment: sure dear and yeah nice to talk with you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not actually written a program which compiles and runs.  If you fix the compilation errors, change the signature of `main` and initialise your collection you will find the program always prints

```
secondname
```

which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
{
    private String name;
    public Student(String pName)
    {
        name = pName;
    }

    public void setName(string pName)
    {
       name = pName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class StudentCollection
{
    private LinkedList<Student> studs;

    public StudentCollection()
    {
       studs = new LinkedList<Student>();
    }

    public void add(Student stud)
    {
       if (stud != null)
       {
           studs.addLast(stud);
       }
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student one = new Student("Matt");
        StudentCollection students = new StudentCollection();
        students.add(one);

        one.setName("Kyle");
        for(Student stud : students)
        {
             System.out.println(stud);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Kyle